# Enter not working for First time in Angular Material

Tags: html, typescript, angular-material

Here is my Html.

When I click on enter, I want click function.

It is not working for first time. Once I manually click on button and then click enter, it is working

```
<mat-card class="example-card">
<mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-title>Login</mat-card-title>
</mat-card-header>
<mat-card-content>
  <form class="example-form">
    <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input matInput placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" required>
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password"type="password" name="password" required>
      </mat-form-field></td>
    </tr></table>
  </form>
</mat-card-content>
<mat-card-actions>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="login()" color="primary" type="submit">Login</button>
</mat-card-actions>
```

Comment: Do you want to submit the form after enter button click?

Comment: Yes, I would like to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`(ngSubmit)`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#onsubmit) of Form Tag:

```
<form class="example-form" (ngSubmit)="login()">
  .......
  .......
</form>
```